# Reducing the Number of Logic Gates by Gate Sharing

Tags: digital-logic

Truth table :

[image]

Circuit : 
[image]

This circuit is created with K-map so it should have been simplified. Is it possible to reduce the number of logic gates by gate sharing? Are there any rule guiding me to do gate sharing?

**Thank you for your help.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance I can see no way of reducing the number of logic gates.  You can only "share" gates if the inputs are the same between instances of a gate, or they share a subset of the inputs that could be separated off into another gate.

The only optimization I can see at the moment is:

$$A_1 = D_2 + D_3$$
$$V = D_0 + D_1 + D_2 + D_3$$

can be re-written as:

$$A_1 = D_2 + D_3$$
$$V = D_0 + D_1 + A_1$$

That just reduces an OR gate from 4-input to 3-input.

Looking at the logic functions like that (+ = OR, × = AND, ¬ = NOT, etc) it is just like working with normal algebra, and you can group and simplify as you would with any other formula.

As an exercise, let's look at the \$A_0\$ output and how it is formed:

$$A_0 = (D_1 × ¬D_2) + (D_3 × ¬D_2)$$

Any repeated terms are candidates for reduction to a single gate - in this case \$¬D_2\$ is repeated, so that is reduced to one NOT gate (as in your diagram).  The same can be done for grouped terms - if you have groups of terms that are atomic (i.e. in the equations \$A × B + C\$ and \$C + A × B\$ the term \$A × B\$ is atomic in that it is the first term evaluated and isn't affected by any other term) then they can be candidates for shared gates as well.

Comment: In general, look at the truth table of the system and see if you can spot truth tables of known gates within the system's table. Pay attention to XOR and NXOR forms, a lot of time they are easy to miss. There are techniques to do gate level sharing optimization after 'formula reduction' however none of them cover everything as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The top line of the truth table should read:

```
     D3  D2  D1  D0       A1  A0  V
   |---|---|---|---|----|---|---|---|
     0   0   0   0        0   0   0
```

Comment: Agreed.  To have an output of "don't care" implies it is connected to an input that is being ignored, and they're not connected to anything specific.  Of course, it could be tri-state, in which case the diagram and the truth table don't match up...